# fadeout sidebar when user doesnt use it for more than 5sec

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, css-transitions, fadein

Expected Scenario: if the user doesn't use the sidebar for more than 5 seconds, the sidebar fadeout (opacity set to 20%) and fade in (opacity:100%) when mouse is 20px nearby.

Current implementation what i got is: when I load the page and on sidebar if its not hovered for 5 sec, its faded out and when i hover on it, it fades in (opacity 100%) and when i hover out (mouseleave) it is 100%.

I am failing to achieve when mouse is 20px nearby - fade in.

```
  const [isSidebarFaded, setSidebarFaded] = useState(false)
  const [isHovered, setHovered] = useState(false)

   useEffect(() => {
    if (!isHovered) {
      const timerId = setTimeout(() => {
        //after 5 seconds if not hovered
        setSidebarFaded(true)
      }, 5000)
      return () => {
        clearTimeout(timerId)
      }
    }
  }, [])
    
  const handleMouseEnter = () => {
    setHovered(true)
    if (isSidebarFaded) {
      setSidebarFaded(false)
    }
  }

  const handleMouseLeave = () => {
    setHovered(false)
    if (isSidebarFaded)
      setSidebarFaded(true)
  }
 return(
      <div
        className={classNames(styles.component, {
          [styles.fadeOut]: isSidebarFaded,
          })}
        onMouseEnter={handleMouseEnter}
        onMouseLeave={handleMouseLeave}
      >
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a wrapper around the actual sidebar, with a padding of `20px`. Put the event handlers on the wrapper.

In my version of your code, there is a single timeout with ref, that the event handlers start/stop:

```js
const { useState, useRef, useCallback, useEffect } = React

const Demo = () => {
  const [isSidebarFaded, setSidebarFaded] = useState(false)
  const timeout = useRef()
    
  const handleMouseEnter = useCallback(() => {
    setSidebarFaded(false)
    clearTimeout(timeout.current)
  }, [])

  const handleMouseLeave = useCallback(() => {
    clearTimeout(timeout.current)
    
    timeout.current = setTimeout(() => {
      setSidebarFaded(true)
    }, 2000)
  }, [])
  
  useEffect(() => {
    handleMouseLeave();
    
    return () => {
      clearTimeout(timeout.current)
    }
  }, [handleMouseLeave])

  return(
    <div
      className={classNames({ sidebarContainer: true, sidebarFaded: isSidebarFaded })}
      onMouseEnter={handleMouseEnter}
      onMouseLeave={handleMouseLeave}
    >
      <div className="sidebar"></div>
    </div>
  )
}

ReactDOM
  .createRoot(root)
  .render(<Demo />)
```

```css
.sidebarContainer {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 0.3s;
}

.sidebarFaded {
  opacity: 0.2;
}

.sidebar {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/classnames/2.3.2/index.min.js" integrity="sha512-GqhSAi+WYQlHmNWiE4TQsVa7HVKctQMdgUMA+1RogjxOPdv9Kj59/no5BEvJgpvuMTYw2JRQu/szumfVXdowag==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: perfect! thats good one! thanks

Comment: You're welcome. Added a clearTimeout on unmount.

Comment: well another use case popped up where if i create a wrapper around with padding on 20px, and if the sidebar is floating then due to this padding of 20px on bottom for example makes UI look wierd. 
how about getBoundingClientRect() to detect mouse pointer near the floating sidebar? is that a possible way to find if mouse is 20px near sidebar then fade in

Comment: You can add a global mouse move event handler and calculate it's positioned relative to the sidebar, but that would be an overkill. Can also add an absolute positioned element that would appear outside of the sidebar and react to the moveover, etc...